# MS-SQL binary viewer

Tags: sql-server

I have been given a MS-SQL database to gleen some reports from. However on first inspection most of the data is stored in binary format. Is there a utility avalible that would allow me to peek at the data in the binary fields to give me some sort of idea as to it's contents.

Comment: Do you know what the binary data actually represents? Is it intergers, dates, characters stored (CAST, perhaps) as binary data? Or is it truly binary data--perhaps encrypted, or the like?

Comment: at this point...I don't know. I am hoping that inspection will reveal the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://octalforty-wizardby.googlecode.com/files/SqlBlobViewer.exe), I wrote one. It's checked by our corporate antivirus, so it should be all safe. Besides, this is a .NET app, so it should be even safer.

Yes, .NET 2.0 is required.

Basic usage is as follows:

```
sqlblobviewer "server=(local)\sqlexpress;initial catalog=mydb;integrated security=true" _
    "select top 10 Binary from TableWithBinary"
```

("_" is line continuation).

What it does is basically exports binary data to files, so that you can examine them later.

[Source code](http://pastie.org/565286) is as simple as it can possibly ever be.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, binaryfield, 0) FROM table
```